# RxJS / Angular2: Why is my subject subscriber not invoked?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a data service which runs queries via HTTP (triggered by some component), then exposes the results via `Observable`. Other components would subscribe to that `Observable` and update their view of the results.

That's the idea anyway, but it's not working. Here's my code.

**ItemListDataService:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ItemListDataService {
  private issues$: Subject<any>;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.issues$ = new Subject();
    this.issues$.subscribe(x => console.log('GOT IT', x));
  }

  getList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.issues$;
  }

  refresh() {
    this.http.get('/whatever')
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .subscribe(data => this.issues$.next(data));
  }
}
```

**ItemListComponent:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { ItemListDataService } from './item-list-data-service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-list',
  templateUrl: './item-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item-list.component.css'],
  providers: [ItemListDataService]
})
export class ItemListComponent {
  data: any;

  constructor(itemListDataService: ItemListDataService) {
    itemListDataService.getList().subscribe(data => {
      console.log('DATA CHANGED');
      this.data = data;
    }, err => {
      console.log('ERR', err)
    }, () => {
      console.log('DONE');
    });
  }
}
```

The subscriber created in `ItemListDataService.constructor` is invoked every time the `refresh()` is called. The only thing that is not working is the subscription in component - neither callback is ever invoked there.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Woo calls refresh()? Where does it get the ItemListDataService from? You've added ItemListDataService to the providers of ItemListComponent, so that component (and its sub-components) will get its own service instance, different from the other components.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, after some research I arrived at the same conclusion. Indeed the issue was that each component got its own instance of the service. Coming from Angular 1 (and numerous other DI frameworks) I was expecting them to be singletons. Live and learn. :-)

Feel free to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As JB Nizet pointed out in a comment, the reason was that the service was not a singleton, i.e. that every subscriber got a new instance. Contrary to Angular 1, in A2 services are not singletons.

In order to have one instance of the service shared by multiple services/components, put it in providers of the parent @Component or @NgModule.

Comment: How do I make sure the service is not instantiated more than once in the root component? I mean (using ng2 in ionic) my components doesn't event have ngmodule.  I was assuming the service defined in the root component ngmodule was singleton but i've just confirmed they have instances for each component.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with ionic, the best I can offer is googling for "ionic service singleton". Here's one of the top results - might work for you: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-create-a-singleton-service/40113/2